# while loop only runs once

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to loop list A and compare each element in list A to list B looking for a match I can't figure out why this while loop is only executing once?

```
for (WebElement webElement : inputs) 
{
    if (webElement.getAttribute("type").equalsIgnoreCase("text")) 
    {       
        String element = webElement.getAttribute("id").toString();
        System.out.println("Element: " + element);

        while(e.hasMoreElements())
        {   
            String param = (String) e.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Parameter: " + param);     

            System.out.println(element.matches(param));
            if(element.matches(param))
            {
                webElement.sendKeys(vars.get(param));
                //inputs.remove(element);
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

Sorry here is the rest of the code, is referenced before the code above

```
        Hashtable vars = new Hashtable();
```

`vars.put("USERNAME","slider");  
        vars.put("POSTCODE","LU1 3LU");
        vars.put("EMAIL","david.cunningham@lumesse.com");
        vars.put("DOB","02 Mar 1983");

       Enumeration<String> e = vars.keys();`

Comment: What exactly is e? I don't see a decleration and initialization. when it only holds 1 element the while loop is only executed once

Comment: What is `e` referencing? Is it an iterator?

Comment: What is ``e``, where is it coming from?  It's not declared in this code.

Comment: what is there in `e` and where have you initialized `e` ?

Comment: This is not enough code... if `e` contains only one element the loop should execute exactly once!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you've got something like:

```
Enumeration e = vector.elements();
```

*outside* the for loop. You need to put it *inside* the for loop, before the `while` loop. Otherwise you're iterating all the the way through it, but never going back to the start.

(I'd also advise you to use the `Iterable`/`Iterator` interfaces if you possibly can, and generic collections.)

Comment: or use `for (String elem : collection)` syntax.

Comment: @AlexR: Assuming the collection involved implements `Iterable<String>`, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you've shown, the enumeration `e` has one element in it. You haven't shown where `e` is created, so nobody will be able to tell you much else.